# Tuple in F# Record

Tags: f#

I am currently in the process of learning F# (only started a few days ago). And I ran into a problem that I can not find an answer to when Googling.

How can I define a member or field in a record as a tuple type?

I would have imagined it would work something like this:

```
type Rectangle = 
{ Coordinates : (int,int)
  Dimensions : (int,int) }
```

But this leads to a compile error (it works if I split the tuples into separate fields).

So how do I define a field that holds a tuple of a given structure?

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use wildcards to define tuples:

```
type Rectangle = 
     { Coordinates : int*int
       Dimensions  : int*int }
```

This notation is based on the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in mathematics

You use parenthesis for instantiating them:

```
let r = { Coordinates = (10,30); Dimensions = (5,5) }
```

Comment: It would be also valuable to explain why multiplication is used.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am pretty sure this MUST be in the MS Docs, right? I guess my eyes slipped over the respective section or example everytime.

Comment: @SugarpinkAI actually it is.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#:~:text=Tuples%20in%20C%23%20are%20structs,you%20must%20use%20struct%20tuples.&text=In%20your%20F%23%20code%2C%20you,result%20as%20a%20struct%20tuple.

Comment: The parentheses are optional here, they aren't required neither in construction `let r = { Coordinates = 10, 30; Dimensions = 5, 5 }` nor in deconstruction `let { Coordinates = x, y } = r`.

Comment: ... and in general parentheses are not specific to tuples at all, contrary to what many beginners are lead to believe. The comma, on the other hand, is. Whenever you see a comma, think tuple.